# If $f$ is continuous and one-to-one, prove that: $(Y,T_b)$ a $T_1$-space implies $(X,T_a)$ a $T_1$-space.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,T_a)$ and $(Y,T_b)$ be topological spaces and $f: (X,T_a) \to (Y,T_b)$ a continuous map. If $f$ is one-to-one, prove that:
>   $(Y,T_b)$ a $T_1$-space implies $(X,T_a)$ a $T_1$-space.

Let $x\in Y$ then $\{x\}$ is closed in $Y$ since $Y$ is $T_1$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}\{x\}$ is closed in $X$. Also, since $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}\{x\}$ is a singleton set.

I don't think that this is enough to show that $X$ is $T_1$ though, since I need to have that **ALL** singleton sets in $X$ is closed. And since we're not given that $X$ is surjective, I cannot explicitly say that every element of $X$ is a pre-image of an element of $Y$, i.e. every singleton set of $X$ is closed.

How can I adjust my proof to prevent this issue? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Functions are surjective to their images. $f$ sends each element of $X$ to a unique element of $Y$, so it is true that each singleton of $X$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x \in X$, the set $\{f(x)\}$ is closed in $Y$, as $Y$ is $T_1$. As $f$ is continuous, the preimage $f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})$ is closed and as $f$ is injective, $f^{-1}(\{f(x)\})=\{x\}$. Thus $X$ is $T_1$